# mbean browser on perfino are missing for my attached VMS

Tags: perfino

I have setup a test perfino server attached the agent to a jvm.

I can see it register and but the mbean browser shows nothing !  is there something I am missing

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the MBean browser?

Comment: Not sure how to do that on here.

but on the page in the section that is meant to have alist of mbeans there is nothing there

i have checked the log files and there are no errors there that I can see that a relevant.

i also added in logfile to the jvm .. but there is no log file being created so ..


also when i go to reporting and try to setup a telemtry and select a jvm to check the mbeans - there is nothing there